# MacOSX - Is it possible to have two internet connections on the same computer?

Tags: macos, mac, internet

I have a Mac and I connect to the web using my cable modem. But I have access to a wifi connection that could give me a second web access.

I can enable both on system preferences, but when I access the web, the iMac uses the wifi.

Each of these connections gives me 30 Mbps.

I was wondering if there was a way to have both enabled and have a sort of 60 MBPS super connection... is this possible? I mean, to combine two accesses and have one big connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leo Notenboom wrote [an article](http://ask-leo.com/can_i_combine_two_internet_connections_to_get_a_faster_connection.html) on the matter a few years back it seems. It should describe to you why this is somewhat pointless.

TL;DR: Expensive, not the purpose of these technologies. If you want faster downloads, [DownThemAll!](http://downthemall.net/) is your friend.

Comment: The OP already has both connections, something the author (and you) dismisses because of costs. The article also clearly states the advantages. It's not "one big connection", but nevertheless useful when multi-tasking/-downloading. Your reply is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It's not costs, necessarily, but it's mainly because it's not the point of this setup. This setup is, essentially, making sure both connections get a similar bandwidth usage to spread out the drain on the connections, or as a fallback if either connection fails.

Comment: Secondly, the article also states that you can only really use one connection at a time.

Comment: If you're replying to other users' comments, mention their username (like in this comment right at the beginning). Only then will they get notified. Regarding that article, I'd love to see where it says that. It only mentions that two computers can only connect via 1 connection. If one is to an FTP server for downloads, and the other is to superuser.com, where's the problem? The article doesn't say.

Comment: @Daniel Beck Well, the article does say that you can: "Each such separate download can happen on a separate connection, thus increasing the apparent download speed of the entire page." Problem is, how much time would it take for any user to make that possible? I doubt even sysadmins can do it in less than a week.

Comment: I read the article and don't see anything to make me think this is pointless: in all but a specific case it is very useful.  The case where it fails is if you're downloading a SINGLE very large thing WITHOUT bit torrent.  And those very large things are exactly what bit torrent was created for, right?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is kind of like an Aggregate Connection. Xserves with two ethernet ports can do it, if ethernet switch supports it, and get up to 2Gbps from the local network. Two internet connections can be aggregated with the right equipment.

The problem is that you're still limited by the one 30Mbps connection. Pulling data from the same connection two different ways can't improve the speed.

Comment: no. I have two links of 30 mbps.

Comment: But you only have one cable modem, no? One of my clients used to have two cable modems and used a Hot Brick load balancer to effectively combine the two cable modem connections.

Comment: I guess OP has his main connection through ethernet, and a 'generous' neighbor is 'willing' to 'share' their wi-fi connection with OP. Kind of what happens to me. So, is this possible?