# Bonding ADSL lines on Mikrotik

Tags: tunnel, pppoe, mikrotik-routeros

I Currently have a Cisco router which I rent from Mweb. On this router I have two incoming 4MB ADSL Lines which mweb bonds for me to acquire 8Mbps. I Don't have any access to the router they do the whole configuration for me.

I Want to know if it is possible to do this myself "bonding" on any of the Mikrotik Routerboards? I Have heard from a friend that he did this by using PPPOE and Tunnels etc. And want to know before trying if it is possible?

Any indication that it would be possible would be appreciated

Comment: You might find [this](http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bridge-two-different-internet-connections) question very relevant.

Comment: Look at cisco config. If it, for example, do multilink pppoe, mikrotik support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a 8M internet from two 4M. This is only possible if they are from one ISP and that ISP supports mlppp, or equivalent LACP protocols (which is rare). but you can loadbalance, and manage bandwidth between devices, and destinations, and protocols, and Many things else.