# How can I use two WiFi connections simultaneosly?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, network-adapter

My Lenovo G50 laptop running Ubuntu has an inbuilt WiFi Adapter, and I also have a USB WiFi Adapter. When I plug in the USB adapter, I see both of the adapters in the Network settings, and they both seem to be able to connect to a router.

I wanted to know if it is possible for me to double my internet speed by connecting to 2 different WiFi APs at the same time, one with each adapter, or if maybe Ubuntu does that already automatically?

If I do have do do something to make this work, please do tell.

Comment: "I wanted to know if it is possible for me to double my internet speed by connecting to 2 different WiFi APs at the same time, one with each adapter, or if maybe Ubuntu does that already automatically?" - It is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound Why not?

Comment: You don't have two seperate internet connections.  Even if you did, you would have to bond those connections together, and that hardware is very expensive.

Comment: [How to bond two different internet connections](http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bond-two-different-internet-connections)

Comment: I do have 2 seperate connections. One is my house Wifi and the other is an open public wifi nearby

Comment: Read the relevant answer about how to bound two internet connections then.

Comment: You will NOT double your download speeds.  **You will be able to maintain two independent downloads, at their respected speeds, but that is NOT doubling a single download.**  So I stand by my "It is not possible" statement.