# How to perform Multipath TCP for bandwidth on Windows® 10?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, network-adapter, bandwidth, gateway

I’m in a situation where I have an ADSL connection over Ethernet and I can use an open Wi‑Fi access point of my neighbour, who has fiber.

I can connect to both networks at the same time, but because of the default gateway rules, all outgoing Internet connections are performed using only one adapter at time. The aim is not only to perform load balancing but to really merge the two bandwidths for a single data stream.

How to perform Multipath TCP for bandwidth on Windows® 10 ?

[Merging two incoming broadband lines for faster Internet](https://superuser.com/q/660798) explicitly asks for a hardware solution, whereas I need a software one especially due to Wi‑Fi.

Comment: For comparison, I have a feature on my Android called`Download booster`in system settings which allows merging bandwith of both Wi‑Fi and ʟᴛᴇ even for a single ᴛᴄᴘ connection (like when downloading a single file). I’ve no ideas on how this is achieved internally.

Comment: I mean an equivalent of MultiPath ᴛᴄᴘ for Windows.

Comment: The duplicate question does not *explicitly* ask for a hardware solution. Regardless, please look at the second highest-voted answer to the duplicate question which proposes a software solution.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator did you pay attention to the diagram ? Now I realize what I want to do is multipath ᴛᴄᴘ.

Comment: I think then your question,*"How to merge bandwidth of both connections even for a single ᴛᴄᴘ connection"* is misleading, since aggregating the bandwidth of your two Internet links (as per the marked duplicate) would satisfy this requirement. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: See also [Can I combine two LANs into one to get double the speed?](https://superuser.com/q/240122/150988)  and [Is it possible to combine two Internet connections to increase performance?](https://superuser.com/q/239546/150988)

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator agregating might only allows load balancing of serveral ᴛᴄᴘ connections.