# Can I use two internet connection in a single PC?

Tags: networking

I'm working now as an Online teaching tutor.

As of now, I'm using the Internet with cable as well. But the problem is it always no signal in the middle of teaching hours.

Since my company is asking for backup internet, would it be possible to use 1 internet connected to my PC?

I'm going to have 1 more internet provider but do I need to use a splitter on the other hand? (like splitter or something).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to combine two internet connections to increase performance?](https://superuser.com/questions/239546/is-it-possible-to-combine-two-internet-connections-to-increase-performance)

Comment: It’s not a duplicate of this question. He’s looking to improve reliability, not performance.

Answer (score 2):

You would need a switch or a router capable of doing failover connections. You basically use 1 conenction at a time, if the connection drops, the router/switch detects it, and fails over to the other connection. In most cases, those switches are enterprise equipment, and are not cheap.

Comment: Sophos UTM can do failover [& other aggregation-type structures] - https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/123530 Your entry-level to Sophos for under 50 seats is freeware, bring your own computer & 2 or more NICs, so you can do it for the price of a junk PC off eBay & an extra pair of NICs. *Edit:* better link for specifics - https://www.fastvue.co/sophos/blog/isp-redundancy-utm-uplink-balancing/

Comment: It’s probably also possible to use OpenWrt with a compatible consumer-grade router. Typically, built-in switches can be configured as required, no need for two true WAN ports.