# Using two different connections (1 ethernet, 1 wifi) in parallel in MacOSX?

Tags: macos, connection-sharing

I use MacOSX and have two connections at home.
I connect to one of them through ethernet, and the other by wifi.
They're two different separate connections from different providers, one is cablemodem and the other is ADSL. (this isn't relevant, but it's to emphasize they are 2 different connections)

Could I, for example, use a torrent client to download from one connection and an eDonkey or other type of client, maybe a web browser, to download from the other connection, thus having more bandwidth?

PS: I know this question is very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/209174/macosx-is-it-possible-to-have-two-internet-connections-on-the-same-computer) but that hasn't been answered anyway.
The [article](http://ask-leo.com/can_i_combine_two_internet_connections_to_get_a_faster_connection.html) linked there, says it can't be done, but it's assuming you want to download the same file from two connections, but doesn't say anything about using two different clients, ports and protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [an earlier SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/42249/how-to-bridge-two-ethernet-ports-on-mac-os-x/42387#42387), you might want to try [IPNetRouterX](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_overview.html). They have some info on [Ethernet bridging](http://www.sustworks.com/site/prod_ipnrx_help/html/InternetSharingHelp.html#EthernetBridging).

[image: IPNetRouterX]

Comment: He doesn't want bridging. He has two separate connections to the internet and wants to use both at the same time.

Comment: Right. Something similar happened in the other question, I don't know if we aren't explaining ourselves clear enough but nobody seems to reply what we asked.

Comment: @Petruza: my mistake. Hopefully someone comes along with a proper answer to your question.

Comment: Well, not the answer I was hoping for, but at least he tried.